# Android : ViewGroup background transparency

Tags: android, animation, background

I have an issue with a transparent CircleView (which extends ImageView and is a square). I made a circular image translate over my CircleView. The problem I encounter is the following :

The gray background you see is a RelativeLayout, I want to hide each corner thanks to the onDraw of my CircleView, because thanks to this feature I will be able to translate the image without showing it outside the circle.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int circleCenter = getHeight() / 2;
    radius = circleCenter;
    loadBitmap();

    if(hideBackground) {
        Path circlePath = new Path();
        circlePath.addCircle(circleCenter, circleCenter, radius, Path.Direction.CCW);

        circlePath.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_EVEN_ODD);
        paint.setColor(0x00000000);
        paint.setShader(null);
        canvas.drawPath(circlePath, paint);
    } else {
        if (image != null) {
            radius -= 5;
            paint.setShader(computeBitmapShader(image));
            canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter, circleCenter, radius, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

And my layout if needed :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/wheel_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.45"
    android:background="#4F4F4F">

    <CircleView
        android:id="@+id/wheel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:text="\?"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="66dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So what I want is to draw a transparent background **over** the background of my RelativeLayout, do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like that in your `onDraw()` method:

```
    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = bitmap.getHeight() / 2;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
```

Read this for more info: [PorterDuff](http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html)